# Too many open files error but 99.5% inodes are free

Tags: linux, centos, file-descriptor

I am getting the error "Too many open files" but 99.5% of inodes are free. The ulimit is 1024 for soft and
and 4076 for hard. Is it possible that the error may be due to some other problem?

Comment: The number of "free inodes" is related to the maximum number of files allowed on a disk. However, your problem is not the maximum number of files existing on the disk, but the maximum number of files that can be accessed the same time.

Comment: Why mention the limit, but not mention how many files your process has open? 
 Presumably, it is hitting the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Inodes are not related to open files. You can check current open files using lsof (sth. like `lsof | wc -l`). I would suggest to just raise the limit in the `/etc/security/limits.conf`

Try adding something like:

```
*  soft  nofile  20000
*  hard  nofile  20000
```

And see if that helps.